# Throw exception including additional line of information

Tags: python

I have some code where I parse a file. It's simple, like so:

```
for line in config_file:
    line_split=line.split("|")
    pid_index = int(line_split[3])
    date_locations = [int(i) for i in line_split[2].split(",")]
    in_file = line_split[0]
    out_file = line_split[1]
    file_info.append([in_file, out_file, date_locations, pid_index])
```

If something occurs I want Python to proceed printing its usual error messages, but I want to add an additional line at the end of the regular error message, something like:

```
except:
    print "line \"{0}\"  might have failed to parse".format(line.rstrip())
```

However, with the code above only the extra info line is shown - the regular error messages are overwritten!

I have tried adding the following to my catch, but it produces ugly output:

```
e = sys.exc_info()
for i in e:
    print i
```

Is there a simple way to have Python print the regular error messages plus an additional line of info of my choosing?

Comment: Don't know if "throw" was the right word. Title improvements welcome.

Comment: Note that the two answers below are both correct, because we've interpreted your question differently. When an error isn't caught in Python, the interpreter prints a traceback _and then stops_. Do you want it to stop or not?

Comment: Yes, I want Python to do what it usually does (just stop) but print an additional info message. Sorry if I did not make that clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best option here (and I removed my other solution in this edit, as I feel it's actually not a great one) is to create your own exception that describes your problem, and then use it atop the exception you have:

```
class ParseFailureError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, line):
        self.line = line.rstrip()

    def __str__(self):
        return "line \"{0}\"  might have failed to parse".format(self.line)
```

then:

```
try:
    ...
except SomeException as exception:
    raise ParseFailureError(line) from exception
```

Which will produce something like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
__main__.ParseFailureException: line "blah" might have failed to parse
```

(I used a `NameError` as `SomeError` for the example)

Note that I have added a specific exception to your `except` line - this is always worth doing, as catching any exception could cause you to ignore errors you don't mean to.

This method has the advantage of making your code easier to use by other software, as they can catch this particular exception.

The `from` syntax on an exception tells Python the root cause of the exception. Otherwise, Python will assume the new exception was an error occurring during the handling of the exception. Note this is only available in Python 3.x, in earlier versions, you will have to do this manually. I would suggest using [`traceback.format_exc()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html#traceback.format_exc) then printing that as part of your exception's error message.

Comment: Tried "except Exception as e: traceback.print_exception(e)" which resulted in TypeError: print_exception() takes at least 3 arguments (1 given)

Comment: You have to get the other arguments from `sys.exc_info`, as in the examples in the linked docs.

Comment: If an exception occurs in that block, is it then interpreted as a ParseFailureError no matter what? Because there are so many exceptions that can happen (NameError, IndexError) I just want to catch any errors and then print that line at the end, without having to guess which ones occur

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it up too quickly, updated, what you want is ``traceback.print_exc()``, which should do what you want.

Comment: @TheUnfunCat If you want to do that you can catch ``Exception`` or ``BaseException`` depending on the range of stuff to catch, but it's really bad practice, as you could catch errors that you didn't expect to, and mask the problem. You can pass a tuple of exception types if you need to catch more than one.

Comment: But if I print all the info about the exception, how do I then mask it? (sorry for being so hopeless) Edit: I mean how do this masking happen? I intend to print all error messages Python would usually print so I do not see how it can do harm?

Comment: @TheUnfunCat I'm not sure what you mean by 'mask' here.

Answer (score 2):

`except` suppresses the error. You want to catch it to print your extra messages -- but then make it come back again. You do that like

```
try:
    raise ValueError("I do not like green eggs and ham")
except ValueError as e:
    print("OK, actually I do.")
    raise
```

In Python 2.x you can only have one exception being thrown at a time. In Python 3 you can

```
raise ValueError("OK, actually I do.") from e
```

to indicate that this error was caused by the previous one.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [logging module](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html):

```
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level = logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

config_file = """\
foo bar
""".splitlines()
try:
    for line in config_file:
        line_split=line.split("|")
        pid_index = int(line_split[3])
        date_locations = [int(i) for i in line_split[2].split(",")]
        in_file = line_split[0]
        out_file = line_split[1]
        file_info.append([in_file, out_file, date_locations, pid_index])
except IndexError as err:
    logger.exception('line {l!r} might have failed to parse'.format(
        l = line.rstrip()))    
    sys.exit()
```

yields

```
ERROR:__main__:line 'foo bar' might have failed to parse
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/unutbu/pybin/test2.py", line 15, in <module>
    pid_index = int(line_split[3])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: I think that tacking a message onto the end of the error is a little hackish - I'm not sure it's a great way of doing this.

Comment: @Lattyware: I agree. That is why I added code using the logging module. I showed how to modify `err.args` because the OP said, "I want to add an additional line at the **end** of the regular error message".